# The logic behind a Early Mortgage Payoff Calculator?

Tags: calculator, finance, pseudocode, computational-finance, amortization

I've been looking around for a Mortgage Payoff calculator and it looks like the ones that are available are primarily commercial.   Does anyone know if it already exists somewhere in script form that could be translated into another language?

If not, is anyone familiar enough with the logic that wouldn't mind sketching up the pseudo-code?  I'll be able to script everything together once it's laid out but all searching I've done so far has only turned up results for creating an Mortgage (not payoff) calculator.

In addition to the obvious utility, hopefully putting this logic out there will help people better understand how their mortgage is being calculated.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.r-bloggers.com/mortgage-calculator-and-amortization-charts-with-r/

The amortization shows you the remaining principal which is the same as the payoff amount.